# how to debug jqGrid not loading with IE9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have a built a asp.net mvc 3 application / iis6 / WCF. When I hit a page with a jqGrid with IE9 sometimes(once a day) it hangs and says : 'Loading..'. However when I do CTRL + F5 it works?

It has no issues when using Chrome and Firefox.

My question is how can I debug this problem or has anyone ever seen this before using a jqGrid?

Answer (score 0):

The odds are it is a browser caching issue. You need to check the HTTP response headers and make sure there is something to the effect of `Cache-Control: no-cache`.